# Symfony: unable to handle request in form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 3 form types (*SearchForm - SearchField - SearchFieldType*), each one including next like this:

`SearchFormType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SearchFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fields', 'collection', array('type' => new SearchFieldType(),
                                                  'allow_add'    => true,
                                                  'allow_delete' => true,
                                                  'by_reference' => false))
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => "Buscar"))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchForm',
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_groups' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_searchform';
    }
}
```

`SearchFieldType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SearchFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'hidden')
            ->add('slug', 'hidden')
            ->add('value')
            ->add('choices')
            ->add('type', new SearchFieldTypeType())
            ->add('actionFilter')
            ->add('actionHighlight')
            ->add('actionShow')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchField'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_searchfield';
    }
}
```

`SearchFieldTypeType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use AppBundle\Entity\SearchOperator;

class SearchFieldTypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $entity = $builder->getData();

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'hidden')
            ->add('operators', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle:SearchOperator',
                                               'multiple' => false,
                                               'expanded' => false))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchFieldType'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_searchfieldtype';
    }
}
```

The form renders properly, but when I submit and try to do `$form->handleRequest($request)` I get an exception:

> Neither the property "operators" nor one of the methods "addOperator()"/"removeOperator()", "setOperators()", "operators()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\SearchFieldType"

That's not true actually, as those methods exist and work correctly:

`AppBundle\Entity\SearchFieldType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\SearchOperator;
/**
 * SearchField
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SearchFieldType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SearchOperator", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="operator_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
   private $operators;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->operators = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return SearchFieldType
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add operator
     *
     * @param SearchOperator $operator
     *
     * @return SearchFieldType
     */
    public function addOperator(SearchOperator $operator)
    {
        $this->operators[] = $operator;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove operator
     *
     * @param SearchOperator $operator
    */
    public function removeOperator(SearchOperator $operator)
    {
        $this->operators->removeElement($operator);
    }

    /**
     * Get operator
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOperators()
    {
        return $this->operators;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

`Stack trace`:

```
 in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php at line 460  +
at PropertyAccessor ->writeProperty (object(SearchFieldType), 'operators', object(SearchOperator))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php at line 104  +
at PropertyAccessor ->setValue (object(SearchFieldType), object(PropertyPath), object(SearchOperator))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 93  +
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapFormsToData (object(RecursiveIteratorIterator), object(SearchFieldType))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 633  +
at Form ->submit (array('operators' => '156', 'name' => 'string'), true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 577  +
at Form ->submit (array('type' => array('operators' => '156', 'name' => 'string'), 'value' => 'felipe', 'name' => 'Nombre', 'slug' => 'nombre'), true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 577
```

**EDIT**:

`Controller Code` :

```
        $searchFormEntity = new SearchForm();
        $searchFormWithValues = $this->createForm(new SearchFormType(), $searchFormEntity, array(
                                        'action' => $this->generateUrl('candidato'),
                                        'method' => 'POST'
                                    ));
        $searchFormWithValues->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Buscar'));
        $searchFormWithValues->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: Do you correctly set the namespaces and `use`-sentences in each class? Where did you define `data_class` for your forms? Did you clear your cache? APC/OpCode cache?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I added some Controller code in OP and more functions of `SearchFieldTypeType` . I think use statements and the other things you ask are set up correctly (yes, I cleared cache also). The form renders correctly and the problem only appears when trying to handle request. Maybe there's an internal confusion with names? There's a `SearchFieldType` entity, a `SearchFieldType` form type and a `SearchFieldTypeType` form type. If I add `use AppBundle\Entity\SearchFieldType` inside `SearchFieldTypeType` I get an error.

Comment: I think that the error in the `use` and namespaces. Post it.

Comment: Added compelte code of form types

Comment: Your code shows entity SearchFieldType.  Is it really SearchField?  Typo in making the question?

Comment: It's not a typo, the entities are : *SearchForm - SearchField - SearchFieldType*, each of them has a form type: *SearchFormType - SearchFieldType - SearchFieldTypeType*, confusing but with namespaces there should be no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a ManyToMany relation, so it would make sense to have the `operators` field be a collection. However you defined it as an entity, so now the form expects to have the `setOperators` and `getOperators` methods as `entity` implies a ManyToOne or OneToOne relationship. 
I think you need to change the statement in the class `SearchFieldTypeType` where adding the `operators` attribute to be the same as what you did before for `fields` in `SearchFormType` if you want to keep the ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: that solves a problem, but what I actually want is a dropdown list with all available operators, I don't need to add new ones, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133664/symonfy-form-type-restrict-entity-field-choices-to-associated-values), where you also answered :-)

Comment: I think we need to mark this as duplicate then or the other one.

Comment: I still am not sure what you are trying to filter by. Are you sure you want to have a ManyToMany relationship? (This is not usally represented by a dropdown but can be done as such from js)

Comment: I'm not sure they are duplicated, they try different solutions for same problem, anyway, finally this is the correct solution, I had a ManyToMany as  I need to model all possible operators that can be used in a field type, but I needed to add an extra single field for the *selected* operator for a field. My error was trying to keep both (possible and selected operators) in the same field. Also, I didn't find a way to mark as duplicate

Comment: Glad you find the solution! I found a guide on this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled . You might be right that they are different but their definition says that 2 questions are duplicate if they have the same solution and are phrased differently. I think you know best if this is true or not.